# how can I write in properties file?

Tags: java

I have a properties file "jpg2dcm.cfg" in witch the properties are set by default. So, I have to add the properties values .how can I modify the file to set the properties values in it with java?

jpg2dcm.cfg :

```
# jpg2dcm Default Configuration for encapsulating JPEG Baseline streams into
# DICOM Secondary Capture Image objects
# (s. DICOM Part 3, A.32.7 Video Photographic Image IOD)

# Patient Module Attributes
# Patient's Name
00100010:
# Patient ID
00100020:
# Issuer of Patient ID
#00100021:
# Patient's Birth Date
00100030:
# Patient's Sex
00100040:

# General Study Module Attributes
# Study Instance UID
#0020000D:
# Study Date
00080020:
# Study Time
00080030:
# Referring Physician's Name
00080090:
# Study ID
00200010:
# Accession Number
00080050:
# Study Description
#00081030:

# General Series Module Attributes
# Modality
00080060:OT
# Series Instance UID
#0020,000E:
# Series Number
00200011:1

# General Equipment Module Attributes
# Manufacturer
00080070:

# SC Equipment Module Attributes
# Conversion Type
00080064:SI

# General Image Module Attributes
# Instance Number
00200013:1

# Image Pixel Module Attributes (detected from JPEG file, if not specified)
# Samples per Pixel
#00280002:3
# Photometric Interpretation
#00280004:YBR_FULL_422
# Planar Configuration
#00280006:0
# Rows
#00280010:
# Columns
#00280011:
# Bits Allocated
#00280100:8
# Bits Stored
#00280101:8
# High Bit
#00280102:7
# Pixel Representation
#00280103:0

# SOP Common Module Attributes
# SOP Class UID
00080016:1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.7
# SOP Instance UID
#00080018
```

Comment: A "witch" you say?!  Anyway...  If it's just a text file, why don't you open it for writing, make changes, and save it?

Comment: And you aren't following one of the countless guides already out there because.....?

Comment: This is too broad a question. Which part do you not know how to do? Read the file into a properties object, manipulate it or write it back?

Comment: Start by learning [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) and [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Comment: manipulate it and write it back

Comment: google, first earch result: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/,

Comment: thanks it helps me lot and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Read the file using FileReader like this:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename); 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader); 
String line; 
while((line= br.readLine()) != null) { 
System.out.println(line);
//Do what you need after reading the file.
} 
fileReader.close();
```

After modifying the string you need to modify or do the work you need with it, just write a new file with the same name on the same location like the this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename);
writer.write(newStringToWriteInFile);
writer.close();
```